# IsHitTestVisible=false does not pass through Button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I tried the `IsHitTestVisible` property to disable the Button and click under the Button.
Button deactivation was successful, but still I can't passing through the button

I am wondering if it can be handled using only XAML or if I need to write additional C# code. 
Also, I would like you to provide a keyword that will solve this problem.

Here is the **MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="Timer.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Timer"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Visibility="Visible" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="{x:Null}" Topmost="True" WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button Click="timer1_Click" x:Name="timer1" Content="Timer1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: What element what do you want to fire hittest? The Grid? Grid has no background by default, set transparent.

Comment: on Button element,
    <Button Click="timer1_Click" x:Name="timer1" Content="Timer1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" **IsHitTestVisible="False"**/>

Comment: "IsHitTestVisible= False" means "neither me, neither any of my visual CHILDREN (important) will fire up any hittest-derived event". Grid is the parent of the button, it will continue firing it. If you want not, set "IsHitTestVisible=False" in the Grid.  Anyways, the question is very unclear, what do you want to achieve? Even more, If you want to disable a FrameworkElement you can set IsEnabled=false. Is more precise than hit-test. Hit-test should only be used in low level visual elements management or when you want keyboard input but not mouse input, is that the case?

Comment: First, apologize for the incorrect question
and Thank you for answering the vague question
I made a mistake because this was the first time I was asking a question.
As a result,
Based on your help, I was able to solve the problem with https://stackoverrun.com/en/q/618396.
Thanks again.

Comment: It is not needed to apologize, don't worry. :)